# Ajax POST request to Shopify's /cart/add.js always returning on error callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, shopify, cart

```
$.ajax({
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    url: '/cart/add.js',
                                    data: {
                                        quantity: 1,
                                        id: form_data
                                    },
                                    success: function(response) {
                                        console.log('in success');
                                        var url = $("#af-btn").attr("href");

                                        window.location.href = $("#af-btn").attr("href");
                                    },
                                    error: function(response) {
                                        console.log(response + "in error");
                                        var url = $("#af-btn").attr("href");

                                        //window.location.href = $("#af-btn").attr("href");

                                    },
                                    complete: function(response) {
                                        console.log(response);
                                    }
                                });
```

Above is my AJAX request. Below is the response Object.
[image: Object Response shows 200 OK response]
Add to cart to shows anonymous behavior, sometimes product gets added and sometimes product is  not added. Can't figure it out. Any ideas?
Below is the form_data
[image: Form Data]

 How I retrieve its value,

```
var form_data = $('form[action="/cart/add"]').find('select[name="id"]').find(":selected").val();
```

Comment: the response object seems to be ok (statusText = ok, responseText is a json string)... what's the error?

Comment: code in error callback function always gets executed, not the code in success callback function.

Comment: Use the other parameters for the error event to get more details: Replace "error: function(response) {console.log(response + "in error");" with: "error: function(response, txtStatus, txtThrown){ console.log(txtStatus); console.log(txtThrown);}"

Comment: txtStatus = parsererror
txtThrown = is syntax error, unexpected token in vendor.js, which is hosted on Shopify cdn.

Comment: And there you have it. Apparently, This is the source of your problem.

Comment: yeah, is my script causing it? what could be the solution to this problem?

Comment: You'll have to look for the source of the vendor.js file. However, I don't see your call for any shopify js files in the code...?

Comment: https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/getting-started/using-ajax-api#add-to-cart

Comment: I am following the above link @Ofir

Comment: Something is weird... shouldn't you pass a token or a special api key with that request?

Comment: I am not making a secure api call, just trying to add product to cart. In Ajax API reference of Shopify there is nothing mentioned about to token either.

Comment: What's the value of "form_date"? Before send the ajax request: add "console.debug(form_data);"

Comment: form_data contains the value of a drop down which has variant id as its value attribute, its unique for every product and its variant. when adding to cart we just have to send this variant_id and quantity.

Comment: I'm trying to make sure you're sending the data in the right way: what's the output of "console.debug(form_data);" ?

Comment: it just contains this number , (30760932813), which is the variant id, and its value is retrieved from a drop down. there is no image upload in comments otherwise i could have shown you.

Comment: Then edit your question and attach it.

Comment: Edited and attached!

Comment: And in this example if you have "console.debug(form_data);" you get the "307..." id?

Comment: yeah ,just 30760932813 ,without double quotes.

Comment: although this is all happening, Product gets added to cart, but with anonymous behavior, sometimes product is added to cart and sometimes its not added.

Comment: We are missing something... I'd recommend that you'll run few tests and track the following: "Has the product been added?", "The error event output", "The console.debug(form_data);" output, the response output. Look for any difference of the cases where the products haven't been added.

Comment: No luck here mate. 'Product not being added to cart' is not occurring somehow. I don't know why.

Comment: Add `contentType: "application/json"` in your AJAX call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it for using the Shopify Ajax Api in Shopify app whose script was added through Shopify Admin API ScriptTag.

1- Load Shopify jQuery Ajax Api Wrapper

```
function loadShopifyAjaxApiScript()
{

var script = document.createElement("script");
script.rel = "text/javascript";
script.src = "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/assets/themes_support/api.jquery-0ea851da22ae87c0290f4eeb24bc8b513ca182f3eb721d147c009ae0f5ce14f9.js";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

}
```

2- Then use it like below :

```
            Shopify.addItem(variantId , 1 , function () {
            console.log('success');
        });
```

Resource Link : [API jQuery Ajax Shopify Sandbox](https://mayert-douglas4935.myshopify.com/pages/api)

Answer (score 1):

The standard AJAX call was throwing errors for me as well in one instance( even thought the product was included in the cart ).

So instead I used their API for the AJAX call. Here is a link to all of the functions: http://mayert-douglas4935.myshopify.com/pages/api

For example adding the items is easy as:

```
  Shopify.addItem($productVal, $productQTY, function(){
    // Do Something here once the product is added
    console.log('Success!!!')
  });
```

PS:

Have in mind that you will be required to include this script in order to have access to the calls:

```
{{ 'api.jquery.js' | shopify_asset_url | script_tag }}
```

Comment: can i use their jquery anywhere? 'cause i am not developing a shopify theme, i am developing an app using PHP.